# SQL - create SQL to join lists

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have the following table:

```
CREATE temp TABLE "t_table" (
  usr_id bigint,
  address varchar[],
  msg_cnt bigint,
  usr_cnt bigint,
  source varchar[],
  last_update timestamp
);
```

Add Data:

```
INSERT INTO "t_table"(usr_id, address, msg_cnt, usr_cnt, source, last_update) VALUES (1, '{44.154.48.125,81.134.82.111,95.155.38.120,94.134.88.136}', 10, 3, '{src1,src2}', '2019-10-16 22:16:22.163000');
INSERT INTO "t_table"(usr_id, address, msg_cnt, usr_cnt, source, last_update) VALUES (2, '{44.154.48.125}', 10, 3, '{src1,src3}', '2019-10-16 22:16:22.163000');
INSERT INTO "t_table"(usr_id, address, msg_cnt, usr_cnt, source, last_update) VALUES (3, '{94.134.88.136}', 10, 3, '{src1,src4}', '2019-10-16 22:16:22.163000');
INSERT INTO "t_table"(usr_id, address, msg_cnt, usr_cnt, source, last_update) VALUES (4, '{127.0.0.1}', 10, 3, '{src1,src5}', '2019-10-16 22:16:22.163000');
INSERT INTO "t_table"(usr_id, address, msg_cnt, usr_cnt, source, last_update) VALUES (5, '{127.0.0.1,5.5.5.5}', 10, 3, '{src1,src3}', '2019-10-16 22:16:22.163000');
INSERT INTO "t_table"(usr_id, address, msg_cnt, usr_cnt, source, last_update) VALUES (6, '{1.1.0.9}', 10, 3, '{src1,src2}', '2019-10-16 22:16:22.163000');
```

Find users who share addresses.

Expected Results:

```
|      users                      |  address                                                    | sum_msg_cnt  |  sum_usr_cnt     | max_last_date                  | source                      |
|---------------------------------|-------------------------------------------------------------|--------------|------------------|--------------------------------|-----------------------------|
|    {1,2,3}                      |  {44.154.48.125,81.134.82.111,95.155.38.120,94.134.88.136}  | 30           |         9        |  "2019-10-16 22:16:22.163000"  |    {src4,src1,src2,src3}    |
|    {4,5}                        |  {127.0.0.1,5.5.5.5}                                        | 20           |         6        |  "2019-10-16 22:16:22.163000"  |    {src1,src5,src3}         |
|    {6}                          |  {1.1.0.9}                                                  | 10           |         3        |  "2019-10-16 22:16:22.163000"  |    {src1,src2}              |
```

**Question:**

How do I formulate a SQL query to obtain the expected result?

Much appreciated.

More info:

PostgreSQL 9.5.19

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: you could split string, find common ips then aggregate query and join the strings back (or keep longest and keep that instead of aggregating)...

Comment: `address[]` seems to store a list of IP addresses. It would be more efficient to use the `inet` data type for that, so `inet[]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the most efficient method, but I can't come up with something better right now.

I assume this will have a terrible performance on a larger table.

```sql
with userlist as (
  select array_agg(t.usr_id) as users, 
         a.address
  from t_table t
    left join unnest(t.address) as a(address) on true
  group by a.address  
), shared_users as (
  select u.address,
         array(select distinct ul.uid
               from userlist u2, unnest(u2.users) as ul(uid)
               where u.users && u2.users
               order by ul.uid) as users
  from userlist u
)
select users, array_agg(distinct address)
from shared_users
group by users;
```

---

What does it do?

The first [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html)  collects all users that share at least one address. The output of the `userlist` CTE is:

```
users | address      
------+--------------
{1}   | 95.155.38.120
{1,3} | 94.134.88.136
{1,2} | 44.154.48.125
{6}   | 1.1.0.9      
{4,5} | 127.0.0.1    
{1}   | 81.134.82.111
{5}   | 5.5.5.5
```

Now this can be used to aggregate those user lists that share at least one address. The output of the `shared_users` CTE is:

```
address       | users  
--------------+--------
95.155.38.120 | {1,2,3}
94.134.88.136 | {1,2,3}
44.154.48.125 | {1,2,3}
1.1.0.9       | {6}    
127.0.0.1     | {4,5}  
81.134.82.111 | {1,2,3}
5.5.5.5       | {4,5}
```

As you can see we now have groups with the same list of usr_ids. In the final step we can group by those and aggregate the addresses, which will then return:

```
users   | array_agg                                                
--------+----------------------------------------------------------
{1,2,3} | {44.154.48.125,81.134.82.111,94.134.88.136,95.155.38.120}
{4,5}   | {127.0.0.1,5.5.5.5}                                      
{6}     | {1.1.0.9}
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=e2acb5d0593bd661c4c333886f36c646)

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name, please can you see the following:  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/251355/postgresql-add-columns-to-query-fiddle-example

Comment: Hi, @a_horse_with_no_name please can you help with the following: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/geB9V6TdHEkF2mSqpd2b4g/1  I have been trying all day, and cannot update your query to include all columns.

Answer (score -1):

Group the addresses using "group by" operator